# Migration takes at least 4 votes?

Tags: discussion, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Require more than simple majority of close votes to migrate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89242/require-more-than-simple-majority-of-close-votes-to-migrate)

I found that instead of requiring 3 votes, now migration requires *4* votes. Why the change? I would like that if 3 people agreed that a question should be migrated, that was already a clear enough a consensus for the migration to happen.

Comment: [Jeff explicitly says it here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89242/require-more-than-simple-majority-of-close-votes-to-migrate/97700#97700)

Comment: sorry, too many bad migrations. If you feel a question was closed as off-topic but *really* needs to be migrated, flag it for moderator attention as such.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the voting system was recently changed to require that **four** out of five people agree on the proposed destination before the question is actually migrated there.

Three used to be sufficient, but it was determined that there were too many poor quality questions getting migrated to sites where they didn't belong. People didn't know how to obey the first rule of migration, that you *don't migrate crap*.

If you don't have a supermajority consensus on migration, then the question is simply closed as "off topic" without it being migrated anywhere. Since that should be your default choice anyway, this is a pretty straight-forward change.

More information here: [Require more than simple majority of close votes to migrate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89242/require-more-than-simple-majority-of-close-votes-to-migrate)

If the question is really *that* good, you can always flag it for moderator attention to get it migrated anywhere on the network immediately, even if it has already been closed. But the fact that scenarios like this will be exceptionally rare is how we know that the change is already a success.