# Why was this post not migrated?

Tags: discussion, support

I cast the final vote to close [The Who's Paying for that Development Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424734/the-whos-paying-for-that-development-model).
When I cast it, there were two votes for it being *off topic*, and two for it being migrated to [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), this is also what I voted for.

So why was it simply closed as *off topic*? Is a 3-2 majority not sufficient to get the post migrated? If I had of known my vote would simply get the question closed I would not have voted at all.

Comment: Why would you have not voted?

Comment: I was one of the migration votes, but I prefer closed to open in any case.

Comment: @Rebecca - i think it is a perfectly legitimate question, just in the wrong place. I personally didn't want it closed, just migrated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Migrations from Stack Overflow [require a majority of 4 votes, not 3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89242/require-more-than-simple-majority-of-close-votes-to-migrate/97700#97700).

Comment: Further details: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89242/require-more-than-simple-majority-of-close-votes-to-migrate/97700#97700

Comment: @sarnold Thanks! I was just hunting for the link. :)

Comment: I've got the [changelog meta answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) [quickmarked](http://vimperator.org/help/vimperator/marks.xhtml#quickmarks), so it is never more than three keystrokes away. :)