# close vote migration conflict

Tags: discussion

Let's say that 5 people vote to close a question, all marking it "off topic".  4 people mark it to go to one site (e.g. server fault) and the fifth person marks it to go to a different site (e.g. super user).  What happens in this case?  Will the question just be closed, or will it be migrated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It'll be migrated to Server Fault. The rule for migrations on SO is that 4 people must vote to migrate to the same target site, else the question will not be migrated. On other sites, the required number of people agreeing is 3.

Source: [Require more than simple majority of close votes to migrate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89242/require-more-than-simple-majority-of-close-votes-to-migrate/97700#97700)

Comment: Is this stated somewhere explicitly?  seems to conflict with John's answer