# Clarify migration process

Tags: feature-request, flags, migration

I believe I have screwed up the migration process more than once when it was suggested that I ask a question in another more appropriate forum.

My current understanding is that I should flag my post for moderator attention and let a moderator migrate a post to another site.
But this is very unclear unless the person who suggests migrating the post happens to also inform you that you don't need to post the question yourself in the new site as part of the migration process, partly because this "process", if I recall correctly, never even uses the term "migration", but only terms like "close", "flag" and "inappropriate", which don't sound very promising for the future of the question! This may be clear in hindsight, but it's very unclear before the fact.

My most recent offense is at [All-or-none exclusive lock on 2 SQL tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265864/all-or-none-exclusive-lock-on-2-sql-tables#comment14818792_11265864) and it's all taken care of now, I think, but I would just like to strongly suggest that the wording of the options in the close or flag process be clarified to indicate to the user that this vote or flag will cause an automatic migration if successful (where appropriate) and you don't need to re-post the question yourself.

Answer (score 3):

What the user interface shows is correct: The question is closed in the site where it is asked, and migrated in the destination site chosen from [at least 4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97700/140449) of the 5 users who voted to close the question. If there are 3 users who votes to migrate, the question is not migrated. The first step is always closing the question, though.

[image: screenshot]

What is not immediately clear is that the migration is a consequence of closing the question as off-topic. If the option to migrate a question would be put together with *exact duplicate*, *off topic*, *not constructive*, *not a real question*, and *too localized*, and not as second option for *off topic*, the option would be more visible, but it would give a wrong impression: You don't close a question because you want to migrate it, but you want to close it because it is off-topic where it has been asked, and there is a better site for that answer.
With the overlap existing between different Stack Exchange sites, *off topic* got a slightly different meaning: The question is more appropriate for another site, where it would get a better answer. For example, a question about Drupal is on-topic on two different sites: Drupal Answers, and Stack Overflow. A question could be voted to be migrated from Stack Overflow to Drupal Answers, but that doesn't mean the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow; it means Drupal Answers is the site where the question can be better answered.

The dialog to flag a question cannot describe when it is more appropriate to flag a question, with all the possible cases, the dialog box would become too big.

What can be done is adding a link to a page explaining when a question should be closed, on the dialog box for closing a question, and a page explaining when a post should be flagged for the dialog box for flagging.
I am not sure how much users would follow the link, but that is the only alternative to search for a question on Meta Stack Overflow, or the meta site for the specific site; although, there isn't nothing that can replace a meta site, and searching for an answer on the meta site is probably the better choice.

Comment: I don't understand your phrase "chose from at least 4". I don't understand your phrase "once shown the [closed] string". Are there grammatical errors here? Also, I don't think you've taken my point. How is a user supposed to know not to post their question in another forum when they close it in the one from which they want to migrate it?

Comment: If three users voted to migrate the question, the question is not migrated. At least four users need to vote to migrate the question (off topic > belongs on), and those four users must select the same destination site.

Comment: When a question was migrated, its title had "[closed]" appended to its title, in the same way it happens with closed questions. There is nothing grammatically wrong in that; it is just that it was not possible to notice which questions were migrated, and which questions were closed, if not looking at the question. What I mean is that, technically, a migrated question is first closed, and then migrated.

Comment: My problem wasn't with the grammar of "[closed]". My problem was with the grammar of your answer. I was having trouble reading and understanding your sentences above. Also, my main problem is not about the question being marked "[closed]" afterwards. My problem is with informing the user what his or her options are. The process doesn't clarify anywhere that a question might be migrated and this will happen automatically. There should be something to clarify that the user should not go post a duplicate question on another forum. After it's migrated is too late. User needs to know in advance.

Comment: I think one more clarification is in order. My concern is about when the person who posted the question wants to migrate his or her own question. The process for migrating other questions is fine, but when a person wants to migrate a question after finding out that it wasn't the best place to post it, the process is very confusing.

Comment: If you want to migrate your own question, you have two options: Vote to close it as off-topic, and to be migrated; flag it for moderation attention. Normally, you will be said to flag it for moderation attention, as it doesn't require 5 users to vote to close it.

Comment: I expanded my answer.

Comment: In my opinion migration is a unique and common enough occurrence on StackExchange sites that it might deserve its own link after "Flag" called "Migrate" (which is why I posted this question as an enhancement request) just because none of those links really look related to migration. The Migrate link could lead to a simple page that explains the options and then leads to existing behavior. Options listed could be "1) Close - 3 other users must agree before migration; 2) Flag - Request immediate moderator assistance in migrating your own post." Really it's no new functionality, just clarity.

Comment: Your option 2 would be repeating the "flag for moderation attention" option that is already present in the flag dialog. Migration on Stack Exchange site is not another type of voting; it is just an option of the closing vote.

Comment: That's my whole point. The functionality is already there. I'm just suggesting a cosmetic improvement to make the *interface* more obvious.