# I messed up my close vote...and now I can't say it should be migrated from StackOverflow to Programmers

Tags: discussion, support, migration, vote-to-close

I don't have a lot of experience closing questions, so maybe this is just me being a newbie, but I'm a little bit confused.

I just voted to close the following question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784710/mvvm-ddd-and-layered-application-project-structure-guidance#comment15654650_11784710

I thought it would be a better fit for Programmers because it seemed subjective and fell under the category of "development methodologies". I left a comment to that effect.

First, I want to say that I have some doubt about whether this question should even be closed (any guidance on this would be appreciated)...

...but assuming it should, I chose the category "not constructive". I believe the question was on topic, just not the type of question that would have a "right answer"--a requirement that is more relaxed on Programmers. Unfortunately, when I went with this option, there was no way to mark that I felt the question should be migrated to Programmers.

If "not constructive" was the incorrect category, what would be the correct category?

If it *was* the correct category, would it make sense to be able to mark the question as more appropriate for Programmers?

If that *doesn't* make sense, would it at least make sense to be able change the category to one that does support migration?

Finally, if changing categories after the fact is too problematic, what about adding some language to category descriptions to indicate whether a migration option will be available?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't change your close vote. But it will only be closed for that reason if two others close it for the same reason. With any luck, other potential close votes will see your comment and act accordingly (though a second non-constructive vote exists). Usually the close reason would be "Off Topic" then you would pick the programmers site. But that site is not currently one of the options. So flagging the question for migration might be a better approach (I do that for questions that belong on dba.SE because there aren't four other like-minded folks that are sufficiently active).

Comment: @AaronBertrand [SO is a special case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97700/131713). Outbound migrations require four votes to agree on a destination.

Comment: Programmers.SE is no longer available as a migration target to community users anymore anyway; a moderator is now required to perform such migrations.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, well I guess that would have been nice to know sooner :) I take this to mean I should have flagged the post instead of trying to close it? Or should I have done both? I've never flagged a post (and don't want to experiment for fear of not being able to retract it), but I assume it allows me type in a comment when I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, migration options are under the "off-topic" close reason. There's a maximum of 5 migration paths and one of them leads here to meta.

However, [Programmers is no longer on the list of community-driven migrations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators), so there's no combination of close reasons and menu options that you could use to cast a migration vote. You can/should flag the question for moderator attention and leave the moderators a note explaining why you think it should be migrated instead.

In this case, I think you're right and the question fits well on Programmers both in  terms of the topic and [being the right kind of subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). I migrated it over.

Comment: Great answer, and thank you for migrating it!

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting a question to be migrated than you can choose "Off Topic". This will allow you to choose between several sites for the question to be migrated to. However, Programmers is no longer an option for migration; therefore, you will have to flag the question for moderator attention and leave a comment regarding your concerns.

Comment: I realized after I submitted my close request that I had chosen the wrong category. Truthfully, though, it still seems like the right category. It was the subjective aspect of the question, not the topic, that caused me to think it should be closed.

Comment: ...and moved to Programmers.

Comment: @DanM that's not a reason to migrate to programmers. Programmers is different in terms of topicality but not very different in terms of allowed subjectivity.

Comment: @BenBrocka, the FAQs seem to indicate otherwise. From Programmers: "What about subjective questions? Subjective questions are allowed, but subjective does not mean “anything goes”. Please keep it professional at all times..." From StackOverflow: "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions..."

Comment: @BenBrocka, also, see this blog post: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/. "Perhaps because our communities have become so accustomed to getting quick, accurate, and timely answers, they feel that even a subjective Stack Overflow is better than the alternatives. So much so, that our fellow programmers created a sister site specifically for their pent up subjective questions...Programmers."

Comment: @DanM that blog post is two years old and PRogrammers' scope has changed considerably.

Comment: @BenBrocka Actually, I think DanM's right here. Programmers does allow questions like this... it seems squarely on topic there to me.

Comment: @BenBrocka Looks ok for ProgSE to me as well...

Comment: @YannisRizos I was just saying "It's subjective" is not a reason to migrate to programmers

Comment: @BenBrocka Well, if it's a good SO question, "it's subjective" does mean that it's probably more suitable for Programmers than SO. But of course it needs to be a good question first, to even start thinking about migrating it (and you know I'm more commenting for everyone else reading this, and not so much for you, you evil double diamond ;)

Comment: @BenBrocka It's also not a reason *not* to migrate it. Context is everything. (We all *love* grey areas, right? Right? _\*sob\*_)

Comment: @BenBrocka, the blog post may be two years old, but it's still referred to in the Programmer's FAQ. If the scope or purpose of Programmer's has changed, how is someone who hasn't been following the evolution of the site closely supposed to know if the FAQs are not current?