# Why was my post closed and not migrated?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions, migration

Respectfully, I'd like to know why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069238/why-cant-i-set-protections-on-root-gvfs was closed with no notes as to why it was closed, or was not marked to be migrated.

Migrating the question would have been the helpful thing to do, IMHO.

I've moved the question to Super User, but would still like to know why a bash script problem doesn't belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Bart Thanks for tagging.

Comment: Keep in mind that those who closed your question might not be aware of which site would be a proper migration target. I personally often have a hunch, but if I'm not entirely sure, I won't select a target.

Comment: Comments still would have been helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because it looked like a [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) question, and there is no migration option for that.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Some folks go on a closing spree w/out using comments to find out what's going on. I moved to SuperUser, because this problem was duplicated on the command line.

Comment: And that may have been the appropriate forum, depending on your level of expertise.  SF is mainly for Sys Admins.

Comment: Also, [migration requires four votes for the target site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89242/require-more-than-simple-majority-of-close-votes-to-migrate/97700#97700) and if two people select just plain "off topic" or another site, the other votes are overruled and the post is simply closed and not migrated.