# Question migrated without sufficient migration votes?

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration

This <s>piece of tu</s> [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260683/yahoo-weather-version-not-supported-issue) was migrated to Super User recently. From the hold reason, it seems 3/5 people chose to vote as

> Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work

So that means, the migration option was not selected. As per [Require more than simple majority of close votes to migrate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89242/require-more-than-simple-majority-of-close-votes-to-migrate/97700#97700), questions on Stack Overflow require 4/5 migration votes. So how did this get migrated to Super User?

Comment: It was migrated @martijn http://superuser.com/questions/615175/yahoo-weather-version-not-supported-issue Sathya, given that you're an SU mod, I guess we can exclude an SO-mod migration to SU?

Comment: Sorry, misread, the history shows it was un-migrated because it was rejected. By Sathya.

Comment: @Bart correct - no Mods were in involved in the migration http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17260683/revisions

Comment: Ah, I should have checked that....weird...

Comment: Confirming - 2 close votes to migrate, 3 as "must demonstrate...". Huston, we have a bug.

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out - I had a bug where if all the voters chose some form of "off-topic" and the last voter chose migration, it would do the migration.

Fixed in next build.  My apologies!