# The Participation Criterion and voting to (not) migrate

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, migration

Say you're working through the close queue, and you encounter a question that is off-topic, but does not appear suitable for migration.  It has three votes to migrate to ServerFault and one vote to migrate to SuperUser.

What can you do in this situation?  Voting to close means it'll be migrated (not what you want), while voting to leave open means it'll stay open (again, not what you want).

Comment: What site are you talking about? You need four to the same site if migrating away from Stack Overflow

Comment: @random, doesn't really matter which site.  Most sites have a threshold of 3, not 4.

Answer (score 4):

It is much appreciated if you judge a post based on your own values and not blindly follow what other users already did on the post. Also being aware that your vote will be binding is great. Please keep doing that.

Migrations are a source of irritation, on both ends of the migration. An important rule to follow is *don't migrate crap* but that is sometimes overlooked. This is caused by the fact that you need to be familiar with or a user on the target of the migration to judge if the question will be closed on the migration target as well. I have misjudged migrations myself.

There are a couple of things you could try but accept failure. You can combine them at will.

- Leave a comment directed at close voters and explain why migration is wrong, click skip on your own review
- Copy the link of the review, Click 'Leave Open' and drop the link in a chatroom for a leave-open-pls request. The [Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) and the [SO Close vote reviewers room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) are open for such requests and if they see fit will follow your advice. If that succeeds those rooms might as well support a correct closure.
- Post on meta of the site and explain why you think it shouldn't be migrated. You either get answers that explain why migration is OK or users will choose Leave Open and close it for the correct reason. In the latter case you have a nice reference for future similar cases.

As indicated by [random](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254764/the-participation-criterion-and-voting-to-not-migrate#comment831965_254764) it does take [4 migration votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97700) for a question to actually migrate (and notice this is for the votes on the Off-topic > Belongs on another site > Migration). Make sure you have a strong case to go against the votes of 4 community members.