# Should the 'close as off-topic' menu provide a write-in option for the alternative site?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review, off-topic

There is only a limited space on the 'close as off-topic' menu for other sites, but there's frequently another site not in the list that might be suitable for the question.  For lack of any other option, these get a comment (if they're lucky) and closed 'off-topic' with no suggested alternative site.

Given the number of possible sites, should there be a write-in option for the alternative site?  The validation could legitimately limit options to 'the trilogy' (since ServerFault isn't listed) plus valid top-level domains of Stack Exchange.

Related questions include:

- [More flexible off-topic migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128617/more-flexible-offtopic-migration_)
- [Should off-topic migration close votes be differentiated from others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76156/should-off-topic-migration-close-votes-be-differentiated-from-others)

but both pre-date the review queues as they now exist.

Comment: Please don't misuse the [meta-tag:bug] tag - it is intended for software bugs in the site, not something like this which is either for discussion or a feature-request.

Comment: Sorry — that's a fair comment, and yes, it was inappropriate.

Comment: I'm sure this will ultimately be closed as a dupe however if something is off topic for your site it really is better just to close it as such. If you think it's worth the effort leave a comment for the OP about a different site. It's really easy for them to copy+paste. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160929/add-flag-as-other-checkbox-to-vote-to-close-as-off-topic-dialog/162109#162109

Comment: +1; I've seen so many questions which I'd like to suggest to move to Programmers, etc. I don't think we should be closing and discarding these questions when they are a good fit for another site.

Comment: @Telthien Not to put you on the spot, but how do you know what an appropriate question for Programmers.SE is if you haven't been a user on the site?

Comment: Maybe the suggested alternative site should not be more than a recommendation (especially if more than one site is recommended).  Maybe it needs human intervention to approve the migration?   OTOH, that's work for someone...

Comment: @Telthien There's a reason the Programmers mods were so happy to get off the quick-migrate list, probably something to do with their 26% rejection rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply flagging the post, choosing "other" (in addition to VtC as off-topic), and expressing your position with details ("would fall under [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) on the other site, which is one of their main foci, and is largely off-topic here") is still the best route to express this.

Obviously, as [nickhar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175602/159165) points out, this makes more work for moderators, but they are the ones that are in a position to be able to readily grab a mod from the target site and run it by him or her, if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I've hit this issue numerous times when a question isn't appropriate for SO, but find myself constrained/frustrated by the options available in the off-topic dialog.

Sometimes, the most appropriate logical option isn't available which forces us to leave a comment rather than programatically suggest the best option from a dialog. Comment votes are usually left in agreement...

I'd be much in favour of more flexible off-topic migration, but, inevitably, there will be more tasks created for mod's and, annoyingly, migrations that are wholly inappropriate for some sites based on FAQ posting rules.

Educating users of on/off-topic subjects is probably the biggest challenge in this and hence why Mod's have [such abilities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/when-voting-to-migrate-an-off-topic-question-why-is-the-list-of-sites-limited) and others do not.

Comment: Actually, educating people who migrate stuff to other sites incorrectly is the biggest challenge. When Server Fault was removed from SO's migration path in excess of 70% of the questions being migrated were being closed for quality or topicality reasons. None of the people who migrated questions to SF knew this as there is no feedback for them on how well they are performing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm [all for a write-in field in that dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187824/188688), but I believe (after reading many answers and comments to that effect) that the consequence of using it should not be a direct vote for migration, but instead a flag for moderator attention. But there is no reason not to [put the choose-other-site radio buttons and the flag-for-moderator-attention tool in the same dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160929/188688).