# How come I can only vote to migrate posts between a few websites?

Tags: feature-request

So I was voting to move a question today and noticed I can only vote to migrate it to a select few sites:

[image]

Sure, these are the most common ones; however there are questions that belong on other stackexchange sites. Obviously, it would be hard to have all of the sites have their own button, so how about a textbox where you can type in the name of the website it belongs on and it will let you pick from the avaible websites?

Comment: See also [Should the 'close as off-topic' menu provide a write-in option for the alternative site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175565/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderators have that textbox! If you would like something moved somewhere not on that list, you can flag it for migration there instead of voting to close.

I imagine the reason behind not providing the textbox is the same as the reason behind taking Server Fault and Programmers off the Stack Overflow migration list — mistaken migrations.

Comment: Oh, so mods can migrate to other sites? Why not give all users that option?

Comment: @chipperyman573: Mistaken migrations. (Two paragraphs!)

Comment: @chipperyman573 because the vast majority of users are not aware what's *really* on topic for the destination site - they go by the name alone